# Neo4j shortestPath

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

I have a graph with 2 types of relationships :

- Type `T1` represents **one way** streets
- Type `T2` represents **two way** streets.

On neo4j document's advice, I want to avoid creating two relationships for two way streets, because it slows down shortestPath function.

But is there any way to traverse `T1` **directional** and `T2` **bidirectional**  in `shortestPath` function?

To be noted, I can't use undirected search because of `T1` relationships!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the cypher `shortespath` function you **can't** do it.

So if you want to use this function, you will have to create two relationships for `T2`.

But when I see `street` and `shortestpath`, I assume you are doing some routing algo, and so the shortespath function is perhaps **not the most optimized** for that.

You should take a look at the **graph traversal API** if you have a complexe routing algo or to **graph algo into APOC** (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress)  with the `AStar` or `dijkstraWithDefaultWeight` procedure.

## Update

This is an example of the query you are looking for with `apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight` algo from APOC :

```
MATCH (from:Way { id: $idFrom }), 
      (to:Way { id: $idTo }) 
WITH from, to
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight(from, to, 'T1>|T2', 'distance', 1) YIELD path, weight
RETURN path, weight
```

Comment: Thanks @logisima for your response. My problem is **not routing**. It's **unweighted** so I guess `dijkstra` is not the best choice. Is there any solution for my problem in **graph traversal API** or **APOC**?